# Python- Card Selection

Tags: python, loops, input

I'm new to python and I'm trying to figure out how to ask the user for input and then use that input to select a specific card from a deck of cards. This is what I have so far

```
cardfaces = []
suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
royals = ["J", "Q", "K", "A"]
deck = []


for i in range(2,11):
    cardfaces.append(str(i))


for j in range(4):
    cardfaces.append(royals[j])



for k in range(4):
    for l in range(13):
        card = (cardfaces[l] + " of " + suits[k])
        deck.append(card)


for m in range(52):
    print(deck[m])
pick=input('Pick a card 1-52 :')
```

Comment: Your question isn't quite specific enough. What's wrong with the code you have so far? Are you getting an error? Is there some functionality you can't find the syntax for?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if all you need to do is access the chosen card.

```
chosen_card = deck[int(pick)-1]
```

Do you need to do more with this?  I would normally think that you'd want the deck to be a list of (suit, rank) pairs, rather than string descriptions.  You can select a card description with your current code, but **deck** doesn't have an easy way to turn those descriptions back into characteristics you can manipulate.

Comment: Won't this throw an IndexOutOfBounds if someone inputs 52?

Comment: Now you'll get a `TypeError` :P

Comment: Nope; 52 gives me "A of Spades", as expected.  How are you seeing a TypeError here?

Comment: `pick-1` is a `str-int`, it gives me a `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`

Answer (score 1):

I assume your problem is that you don't know how to access the chosen card, once the player picks a number.

If that's the case, you're already close to the solution!

When the player inputs a number, you've stored it as a string in the `pick` variable. The next steps are to:

1. convert that string to an integer, and
2. find the card at that position in the deck.

Python has a [built-in `int` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), to convert the pick from a string to an integer.

Your `deck` variable is a list, and to get items out of a list in Python, you can request the item by index. The index is a number representing the position of that item:

```
animals = ["cat", "dog", "fish", "pterodactyl]
print(animals[0]) # "cat"
print(animals[1]) # "dog"
print(animals[2]) # "fish"
```

Adding this to your code should do the trick:

```
pick = int(pick)
card = deck[pick]
print("Your card is", card)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there!  All you need to do is to get the card out of `deck`.

```
pick = input('Pick a card 1-52 :')

card = deck[int(pick)-1]

print("You chose: The {}".format(card))
```

(Psst!  remember, lists start at index `0`, that's why you have to `-1` from it)